# Dapper ORM not accepting multiple models

Tags: database, orm, dapper

I am having a problem were Dapper won't accept multiple models, see my code example. I have the QueueItems and robots models in query but when I add the second (Robots) I get the folowing error "IDBconnection does not contain a definition for Query"

```
public void getdata()
{
    using (IDbConnection connection = new SqlConnection(con))
    {
        string sql = "Select * from QueueItems";

        var queryResult = connection.Query<QueueItems,Robots>(sql).ToList();

    }
}
```

Comment: I have installed dapper from nuget and have the using dapper statement at the top of my cs file. It's only when I put more than one model in

Comment: Either use a grid reader to map multiple resultsets into multiple objects or multi mapping to map a single resultset into multiple objects. What exactly are you trying to do? Please show your QueieItems and Robots classes and the columns returned from your query.

Comment: Im trying to do a join between the two tables. How do i use the multi mapping i think that is what im going for. The QueieItems and Robots classes are just pocos representing the tables in the database.

Answer (score 1):

If your resultset contains columns for two pocos, you'll have to wrap them in an envelope (either a typed class or dynamic) object since you can only return one type.

The method signature for that is

```cs
var result = connection.Query<QueueItems,Robots,dynamic>(sql, (queueItem,robot) => {
                       dynamic d = new ExpandoObject();
                       d.QueueItem = queueItem
                       d.Robot = robot; 
                       return d;
                     }, splitOn: "...insert split columns unless they're named Id...");
```

This will return a dynamic list where each record contains a QueueItem and Robot property.

Dapper by default splits on the "Id" column. If your query returns a recordset like this:

`|Id|C1|C2|C3|Id|C4|C5`

Id, C1, C2 and C3 will be mapped to queueItem, Id, C4 and C5 will be mapped to robot.